# chaincode argument error: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: bash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created a test network and I am able to install the chaincode I have created in golang. But when instantiating it I receive the following:

```
2020-03-24 08:00:00.843 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 04a Using default escc
2020-03-24 08:00:00.844 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 04b Using default vscc
Error: chaincode argument error: unexpected end of JSON input
```

If I build the code in its own directory, it compiles without problems.

I can install and instantiate the code in another development network, but not in one I have created from scratch.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The instantiation command would be helpful. It looks like some problem with the JSON format of the input, maybe some characters that need to be escaped or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotation marks when referencing `CC_CONSTRUCTOR` variable. Otherwise, bash prioritizes inner spaces over inner quotation marks:

```sh
peer chaincode instantiate -C $CC_CHANNEL_ID -n $CC_NAME -v $CC_VERSION -c "$CC_CONSTRUCTOR" -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!

I still do not understand why does work without quotations in the other environment...

Comment: Maybe the shell interpreter. It seems that you are running the commands from inside the container, but if this container is running Fabric 1.X (Debian-based) and the other Fabric 2.0 (Alpine-based), they may use different shell interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I am setting env variables, then call the instantiate. Same variables are set for the install, which works fine.

```
export CC_CONSTRUCTOR='{ "Args" : [ "Message" , "Hello World - Init message" ] }'
export CC_NAME="testcc"
export CC_PATH="testcc"
export CC_VERSION="1.1"
export CC_CHANNEL_ID="testchannel"

peer chaincode instantiate -C $CC_CHANNEL_ID -n $CC_NAME  -v $CC_VERSION -c $CC_CONSTRUCTOR  -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS
```

I have tried escaping some that might need, that does not work. And again, the very same golang code and JSON constructor works on another test environment.

If I unset the CC_CONSTRUCTOR variable, I receive another error message, hence with high probability that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In same cases, this error is generated by

```
const stateValue = await ctx.stub.getState(state);
```

when the state does not exist.

In other cases, it is because
`evaluateTransaction` is used instead of `submitTransaction` when reading states